# Java. instanceof с переменной класса

Tags: java, рефлексия

Почему у меня не получается использовать во втором аргументе операции instanceof переменную типа Class? Пример:

```
Class mClass= SomeClass.class;

If(someObject instanceof mClass) 
     Return;
```

П.с. 
Забыл добавить, что instanceof мне нужен потому что в условии ожидается что наследник указанного класса так же вернёт истину. Такое возможно с переменной?

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Компиляция не проходит? Исключение вылетает?

Comment: Потому что операнд `instanceof` проверяет принадлежность объекта к указанному экземпляру, не переменной/объекту. А вы сравниваете два объекта. Правильнее сравнивать `if(someObject instanceof SomeClass)`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev компилятор не воспринимает переменную

Comment: @Rootware так если я не могу указать конкретный класс, у меня на получится использовать instanceof, так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если класс, принадлежность объекта к которому вы хотите проверить, не известен на этапе компиляции - делайте это так:

```
if (someObject.getClass().equals(mClass)) {
}
```

Вариант с `isInstance` проверит еще все суперклассы вашего `someObject`.

```
if (mClass.isInstance(someObject)) {
}
```

Comment: Черт, забыл указать, что мне нужно проверять, является ли объект не только экземпляром но и наследником класса из переменной

Comment: А почему не isInstance?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, тоже вариант. Опубликуете?

Comment: @Nofate кстати, есть ли разница, использовать `equals` или `==` в этом случае? Даёт ли `java` гарантию, что хотя бы `getClass()` и `.class` будут возвращать один и тот же экземпляр всегда? (Т.е. я имею в виду все способы получения объекта `Class` кроме непосредственного его создания через `new`)

Comment: @selya, да это все ссылки на экземпляры `Class`, созданные загрузчиком классов. Так что для одного загрузчика экземпляр будет один.

Comment: @Nofate но для того, чтобы лишний раз не встрять, лучше все же использовать `equals`, да?

Comment: @selya, просто хорошая привычка. Формально в исходниках `java.lang.Class` метод `equals` никак не переопределен, так что он эквивалентен `==`.

Comment: @Nofate "опубликовал" :-)

Comment: @Nofate ой, прошу простить мою забывчивость. Почему-то спутал `new Class<SomeType>` и `Class<SomeType>`, который сам же писал, описывая сигнатуру очередной функции. Там же нет общедоступного конструктора, так что да, система может гарантировать, что будет существовать один экземпляр `Class<SomeType>`...

Answer (score 3):

**1 вариант** Работает с типом

```
if (someObject instanceof SomeClass) 
    return;
```

**2 вариант** Работает с экземпляром типа

```
if (SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom(someObject.getClass())) 
    return;
```

Comment: А почему не isInstance?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, для наглядности. Хотя если брать именно спецификацию, то у instanceof эквивалент - isInstance.

Answer (score -1):

В общем если кому то тоже интересно, то вот такой ответ я придумал на свой же вопрос

```
public boolean isInstanceOf(Class fClass)
{
    Class fThis=this.getClass();
    while(fThis!=ArhiClasd.class)
    {
        if(fThis==fClass)
            return true;
        else
            fThis=fThis.getSuperclass();
    }
    return false;
}
```

ArhiClass это тот самый самый супер класс, до которого нам интересны все совпадения. Можете указать хоть Object.

Comment: что такое `ArhiClasd`?

Comment: @Nofate имя того класса, в чьем дереве наследнований нам интересно получить ответ true. Например там можно поставить Object, или Employer , если мы решаем популярную в учебниках задачку

Comment: Тогда стоит его вынести в параметры метода.

Comment: @Nofate ну я так подумал, это уже не напрямую относится к теме, так как опять же можно написать туда Object, и это будет работать в любой реализации, только медленнее